Can't type ê (^ + e on my French keyboard) anymore. Dead keys and Ctrl-Shift-u aren't working anymore. But my keyboard has still French layout
(EDIT: eventually, it's a Debian regression that should be corrected soon. Avoid updating to the 6.1.0.21-amd64 image until then)
On Debian 12 (6.1.0-21-amd64), GNOME, I was writing a message fast on Firefox, and I did a wrong move.
By accidentally hitting some keys (but I wonder which ones), I've managed to disable the diacritic normal management.


I'm unable to type ê = (^ + e) anymore.

another symptom is that the ` (backtick?) is a dead char in French
(` + e should lead to è, and when I type the ` char, GNOME should wait for the vowel to be typed).
But it isn't anymore and displays the ` immediately.

If I attempt an Ctrl-Shift-u + 2192 to have the right arrow, it blocks the caret the time to take the numbers and release it after, but don't type the character.
If I do so under gedit, in example, nothing will appear.

It's not possible to type the ^ alone. I can hit it ten times, it won't display a single one.

If I enter IntelliJ, I can see that GNOME "sees" the dead keys coming. But at the end it does nothing with what is composed:



starting typing Ctrl-Shift-u + 2192, here At the end, the tooltip will disappear, and it won't have any effect -
I can't use dead char keys anymore.

Even not in a terminal.

no way to type ^  or ê

A reconfiguration of the keyboard didn't helped


sudo dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration


Nor a reboot

My input source configuration is:


Others attempts:
localectl

System Locale: LANG=fr_FR.UTF-8
    VC Keymap: (unset)         
   X11 Layout: fr
    X11 Model: pc105
  X11 Variant: azerty

If I execute:
xev -event keyboard

and hit: ^ + e should lead to è
I see that:
KeyPress event, serial 28, synthetic NO, window 0x2800001,
    root 0x1d9, subw 0x0, time 3012274, (519,437), root:(619,606),
    state 0x10, keycode 34 (keysym 0xfe52, dead_circumflex), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 1 bytes: (5e) "^"
    XmbLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: True

KeyRelease event, serial 28, synthetic NO, window 0x2800001,
    root 0x1d9, subw 0x0, time 3012334, (519,437), root:(619,606),
    state 0x10, keycode 34 (keysym 0xfe52, dead_circumflex), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 1 bytes: (5e) "^"
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyPress event, serial 28, synthetic NO, window 0x2800001,
    root 0x1d9, subw 0x0, time 3013054, (519,437), root:(619,606),
    state 0x10, keycode 26 (keysym 0x65, e), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 1 bytes: (65) "e"
    XmbLookupString gives 1 bytes: (65) "e"
    XFilterEvent returns: True

KeyPress event, serial 28, synthetic NO, window 0x2800001,
    root 0x1d9, subw 0x0, time 3013054, (519,437), root:(619,606),
    state 0x10, keycode 0 (keysym 0xea, ecircumflex), same_screen YES,
    XKeysymToKeycode returns keycode: 27
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XmbLookupString gives 2 bytes: (c3 aa) "ê"
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyRelease event, serial 28, synthetic NO, window 0x2800001,
    root 0x1d9, subw 0x0, time 3013124, (519,437), root:(619,606),
    state 0x10, keycode 26 (keysym 0x65, e), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 1 bytes: (65) "e"
    XFilterEvent returns: False

What should I do?

Does pressing Super+Space (the Windows key and space) fix things?

@StephenKitt No, it doesn't

@StephenKitt I guess it's a graphical or typing handling problem that GNOME encounters, and not a keyboard problem or layout problem. The fact that when I open gedit and type Ctrl-Shift-u +  2 1 9 2 it doesn't make the \u2192 appearing underlined as usual waiting for completion before showing the wished character, but instead do wait some actions on the keyboard but show nothing and does nothing at the end, I think it's a bug of GNOME coming with the last update.

I have the same problem with Portuguese Brazilian layout, the layout and every configuration is as expected but the dead key characters never appear on the screen.

The patch is here. An  apt-get update will correct the issue.

Coming nearer to a solution, at least a bypass (please tell me what would be the side effects of it):
Uninstalling iBus made the problem disapear.
After reboot all diacritical characters are now functional on the keyboard.
Want some? àèùòôêû...
And Ctrl-Shift 153 enter... gives me the œ my keyboards mappings are never able to give directly.
I have a vague souvenir of another keyboard problem I had solved by uninstalling or disabling ibus. That makes it the first thing to try for problems of that kind. For mission critical systems,I plan to always uninstall it.
Hoping ibus gains stability...
